# how do i recover my eth sent eth from bnb to trezor wallet using arb as gas price is cheaper it says it been sent but not in my trezor wllet

Tags: wallet-transfer, hardware-wallets

how do I recover my eth sent from BINANCE Exchange I  sent my  eth from BINANCE exchange   to my cold  wallet using arb as gas price is cheaper  it says it been sent but not in my  wallet.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in an arbitrium explorer if the ethers are in your address.

Another alternative is to use a wallet that supports both Arbitrium and Trezor. For example Metamask supports both.